# How to find the most frequently visited 3-webpage sequence from a large log file with userID and pageID

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting, dictionary

Given a log file of webpage visited as:

```
Userid  PageID
A          1
A          2
A          3
B          2
B          3
C          1
B          4
A          4
```

Find the most frequent visit sequence of page-ID:

```
 for A : 1-2-3, 2-3-4
 for B : 2-3-4
```

so, 2-3-4 is the most frequent.

My idea:

1. Put each item of the file into `map1<key:user_id, list<pageID> >`.
2. When `list.size() == 3`, create a new struct `three_hits` to hold the three pageID.
3. Put it in into `map2<struct three_hits, int counter>`.
4. Then, find the item in map2 with largest counter value.

Declarations:

```
 struct three_hits
 {
     int f_page;
     int s_page;
     int t_page;  
 };
 map<string, list<int> > map_hit;
 map<struct three_hits, int> map_t_hits;
```

Scan records:

```
for each( record: r in log)
{
    if(map_hit.count(r.userid) >0) 
    {
        map_hit[r.uid].second.push_back(r.pageID);

        if(map_hit[r.uid].second.size() ==3)
        {

            list<int> tmp=map_hit[r.uid].second;

            t_hits(tmp[0],tmp[1],tmp[2]);

            // O(n lg n)
            if( map_t_hits.count(t_hits) >0)
                map_t_hits[t_hits]++;
            else
                map_t_hits[t_hits]=1;
        }
        else
        { 
            list<int> tmp(r.pageID);

            map_hit[r.uid]=tmp;
        }
    }
    // O(n)
```

Iterate `map_t_hits` once to locate its key (`t_hits`) with highest value.

The time *O(n* lg *n)* and space *O(n)* for a maps.

Any better solutions?

Comment: To show a block of code in your question, start with an empty line, then lines of code started with 4 spaces, and end with an empty line.  For positioning in the code, use spaces; don't use any tabs.

Comment: Does it matter if {A, 4} happened 18 hours after {A, 1, 2, 3}? 56 hours after?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider doing this with sort-merge. First use a stable sort by user id to put all of the sequences for a given user together, keeping the original order. Then sort all the 3-web page sequences, and finally count runs of equal sequences. This is also O(n log n). It probably takes a bit more time in practice, but might take less store if run using internal memory, and can be run with sorts in external memory, if you have too much data to fit in store at any one time. Whether it's actually any better depends on the details of your particular situation.